# Armstrong Numbers with boundaries function help in R

Tags: r, function, numbers

Please take a look at the attached image. This is what the code in R should provide. I am struggling to write the relevant code to meet all the requirements:

[image]

This is the code I have tried so far:

```
>num = as.integer(readline(prompt="Enter a number: "))
>sum = 0
>temp = num

>while(temp > 0) {
digit = temp %% 10
sum = sum + (digit ^ 3)
temp = floor(temp / 10)
}

>if(num == sum) {
print(paste(num, "is an Armstrong number"))
} else {
print(paste(num, "is not an Armstrong number"))
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you started.

1. Define a function that returns `TRUE` or `FALSE` depending on whether your number `x` is an Armstrong number.

   ```
   is.ArmstrongNumber <- function(x) {
       temp <- x;
       sum <- 0;
       while(temp > 0) {
           digit <- temp %% 10
           sum <- sum + (digit ^ 3)
           temp <- floor(temp / 10)
       }
       if (x == sum) TRUE else FALSE;
   }
   ```
2. We can apply this function to the sequence of integers `1:1000` and only return those numbers that are Armstrong numbers:

   ```
   (1:1000)[sapply(1:1000, is.ArmstrongNumber)]
   #[1]   1 153 370 371 407
   ```

I'll leave the I/O bits up to you.

Comment: Thank you so much Maurits ! This helped me a lot !!